# Getting and Setting arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, get, set

The aim here was to create a player object array with 16 players in the main class, and then get and set each value all at once, I'm guessing what I'm trying to do is either impossible or I'm just wording it wrong.

```
package Part1;

public class Player {

String name[] = new String[16];

    //no errors here, the setting of the playerNames seems to work fine.
public void setName(String playerName[]){
    for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
        playerName[x] = "Player ";
        name[x] = playerName[x];
    }
}
    //this is where my errors are, I've got one one under the "[]" after getName
    //the error is "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"
public String getName[](){
    for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++){ 
    //and another here, under "return name[x];"
    //the error is "void methods can not return a value"
    //this error seems a bit weird seeing as my method is a String, not void, at first I thought I don't have enough braces but it seems to be fine.
        return name[x];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should always place the brackets `[]` directly behind the type, from which you are creating an array. Your field name - for example - is a string array. That is expressed as `String[] name`. Java unfortunately allows the other syntax, which was very common in C (as I remember correctly). Your `getName` method has the same problem, and - as I assume you want to return the whole array - is wrongly implemented.

Comment: You're currently not making use of `setName`'s argument `playerName`: you override all the data it contains, putting the same string `"Player "` in every cell, not very useful. What are you passing on to this method? What's your purpose here?

Answer (score 0):

- You have wrong method definition remove `[]` from `getName[]()`. `getName` isn't array.

> The only required elements of a method declaration are the method's return type, name, a pair of **parentheses, ()**, and a body between braces, {}.

It should be

```
public String getName(){
for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++){ 
  ....
  ...
```

- One more thing

> **Do not return from an loop.**
>   Instead return an array

### See also

- [methods oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

public String getName

wrong initialization of method

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return the name array, just do the following

```
    public String[] getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what setName method is meant to do. All the names (all places in both arrays) are initialized with string "Player ". Maybe you meant following?

```
for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++){
    playerName[x] = "Player " + x;
    name[x] = playerName[x];
}
```

In getName you have wrong construction

```
getName[]()
```

maybe you meant something like that

```
  public  String[] getNames() {
// Method code
}
```

Right now getNames returns the first element in the array...

Comment: Yeah this is what I meant, everything here fixed my errors. Thanks.

Comment: With your version of `setNames` the OP will still lose the input names given by `playerName` array. If what the OP wants is your result, then no array is needed as parameter of this method.